# Render a React component by mapping an array inside of an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects, react-component, array.prototype.map

I have trouble rendering a react component by mapping an array nested inside an array of objects.

I have this React component, which is simple images

```
function ProjectLangIcon(props) {
    return (
        <img className="project-icon" src={props.src} alt={props.alt}/>
    )
}
```

This component is a part of this bigger one :

```
function Project(props) {

const projectLang = projectList.map(projects => {
    return projects.lang.map(langs => {
        return <ProjectLangIcon
            key={langs.key}
            src={langs.src}
            alt={langs.alt}
        />
    })
})

return (
    <div className="project">
        <a href={props.link} className="project-txt" target="_blank">{props.title}</a>
        <div className="project-content">
            {projectLang}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I'm mapping the data from this file :

```
const projectList = [
    {
        key: 1,
        name: "Site de mariage from scratch",
        link: "https://mariage-hugo-et-noemie.fr/view/index.php",
        lang: [css, html, javascript, php, mySql]

    },

    {
        key: 2,
        name: "Site de paris sportifs",
        link: "https://akkezxla.ae.lu/Akkezxla-Betting-Site/bet-list.php",
        lang: [css, html, javascript, php, mySql]
    },

    {
        key: 3,
        name: "Site de location d'appartement",
        link: "http://paris-island.com/",
        lang: [wordpress, css, javascript]
    }
]
```

with the lang array being constitued of objects like these :

```
const css = {
    name: "CSS",
    src: cssIcon,
    alt: "Icône CSS"
}

const html = {
    name: "HTML",
    src: htmlIcon,
    alt: "Icône HTML"
}
```

Then, I map the projects component inside the Realisation component like this :

```
function Realisation() {

const projects = projectList.map(item => {
    return <Project
        key={item.key}
        title={item.name}
        link={item.link}
    />
})

return (
    <div className="realisations pro-block">
        <BlockTitle
            title="Réalisations"
            close={closeReal}
        />
        <div className="realisation-content">
            {projects}
        </div>
        <BlockNav
            left="Compétences"
            switchl={switchComp}
            center="Parcours Porfessionnel"
            switchc={switchParcoursPro}
            right="Parcours Académique"
            switchr={switchParcoursAcad}
        />
    </div>
    )
}
```

the result I get is this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oetw1.png)

But I want each projects to have its corresponding language icons.

Does anyone have an idea of hiw I should proceed ?

Comment: How do you map `Project` components? You need to map projectList.map ProjectComponent and pass a project as a parameter, then you will be able to map projectLang for this specific project you passed instead of mapping ALL the projects in `const projectLang`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I updated my question to show you how I map the Project component. 
I was under the impression that I should change something inside the projectLang variable, so each project would have their own language Icons. but I don't seem to manage that, my comprehension of react componet and/or map method doesn't seem to be good enough

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to Project component. You are rendering this component for each Project of projectList but inside of this component you are not taking in the account the actual Project that is passed to this component.

Project (component)

```
const projectLang = projectList.map(projects => {
    return projects.lang.map(langs => {
        return <ProjectLangIcon
            key={langs.key}
            src={langs.src}
            alt={langs.alt}
        />
    })
})
```

Lines above are building the same projectLang for any Project you passed to this component. And is building it from All the projects you have, it returns the array of arrays. So [[all_icons_of_project_1], [all_icons_of_project_2], ...].

Here is what you should do:

First: You need to modify Product component to either pass a product item itself, either to pass additional property, `langs` in your case. And to modify .map function a little.

Notice: i destructured the props object passed as a parameter to Product component. Also, i wrapped the map function into useMemo for optimization purposes.

```
function Project({ title, link, langs }) {
  const projectLang = useMemo(() => {
    return langs.map((lang) => (
      <ProjectLangIcon key={lang.key} src={lang.src} alt={lang.alt} />
    ));
  }, [langs]);

  return (
    <div className="project">
      <a href={link} className="project-txt" target="_blank">
        {title}
      </a>
      <div className="project-content">{projectLang}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Second - just pass the `langs` attribute (prop) to your Product component. (Again, i wrapped it into useMemo, for optimizations)

```
function Realisation() {
  const projects = useMemo(() => {
    return projectList.map((item) => (
      <Project
        key={item.key}
        title={item.name}
        link={item.link}
        langs={item.lang}
      />
    ));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="realisations pro-block">
      {/* ... */}
      <div className="realisation-content">{projects}</div>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit lucid-black-xniej1]

Note - no icons in codesandbox, only placeholders and alt text.